# Is there any ways to find our latest pull commit Id in git?

Tags: git

Me and my friends doing some collaboration to develop something and we put it on git.

Recently, my friends have done such a lot of commit and push into our git and, unfortunately, I have not done any git pull.

So my question is, Is there any ways to find which `commit id` that I have pull recently? Or maybe just the latest pull that I have done.

Thank you I'm newbie here so hopefully you get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Tags are used to help people find questions better and faster. Please use tags wisely. This question doesn't appear to be related to either [tag:github], [tag:gitlab] or [tag:bitbucket]. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530707/is-there-any-ways-to-find-our-latest-pull-commit-id-in-git#) it to remove the tags that are out of scope.

Comment: Apart from the issue with tags, your question also lacks clarity, hence the speculative nature of the answers. Please state more clearly exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Hi, my apologies for using tags incorrectly. Thank you for the advice

Comment: @th33lf My bad for coming up with confusing questions, I have tried to edit it and hopefully make sense now.

Comment: No problem: the site has a little slope at the beginning of the learning curve.
You state "you are not doing any `git pull`", but you want to find out the latest commit you pulled. This part is yet unclear: git does not pull anything for you. Moreover, please be aware that pull stands for fetch (getting the commits from the remote) and merge (integrating edits in your current development branch).

Comment: @andikabhas Doesn't `git log` give you this information?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that one way to quickly see what your latest `git pull` was, is to go and search the reflog.

If you type

```
git reflog | grep "pull"
```

You'll get a list of `pull`s. It will also show you the sha1 of the commit for which the pull was done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done `git pull` (or `fetch` or `push`) at least once you now have the branch `origin/master` which points to the commit you last fetched/pulled/pushed.

And I think you don't even need it. The command

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

will pull new commits from your central remote and rebase your unpushed commits on top of that. Fix merge conflicts if any and push your new commits:

```
git push origin master
```

PS. I suppose the remote is named `origin` and the branch is `master`. Put your proper names.